# autogen throws errors in the output

Tags: python, openai-api, autogen

Unfortunately, I somehow volunteered for the university to deal with autogen. I also understand the sample codes well and now wanted to develop my own CoLab book Autotgen environment. However, when recreating the examples, I always get thousands of error messages in the output.
Can someone take a look at my colab notebook? I can't get any further here.

It seems some issue with open connection.
openai.error.ServiceUnavailableError: The server is overloaded or not ready yet.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LtRm8rhV2Qlmx5gJVoNPAJlfU9_LvWUO?usp=sharing#scrollTo=_3rYVUua891L

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to do “ url extraction based coding works”

Your execution output reads the error.

First of all, autogen does not truly automate everything. At the end of the day, you have to set up a systemic framework using web scraping technique and different functions that can do what you are asking the bot to do. Hence, you’ll have to be able to program the non autogen approach before you can even adapt the auto gen framework for url extraction based coding works

Second, “unfortunately somehow ended up here” is never a responsible frame of thought, don’t ever use that on the internet or in front of potential recruiters, friends sure, otherwise you leave a bad remark about how others perceive you and your questions and motives.

Don’t do it any longer if you don’t want this task, this is a long grind ahead…